# ExecuteScalar not functioning on server

Tags: oracle, .net-2.0

The application uses Oracle DataAccess ver. 1.1.  , VS 2008, .Net Framework 3.5 w/SP1

```
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionStringLogon);
connection.Open();

OracleParameter selectParam = new OracleParameter(":applicationName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 256);
selectParam.Value = applicationName;

if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    connection.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = "Select ApplicationId from Applications where AppName = 'appName'";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

if (selectParam != null)
{
        cmd.Parameters.Add(selectParam);
}
object lookupResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();

if (lookupResult != null)
```

The procedure fails on object lookupResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); with this error:

Event Type: Error
Event Source:   App Log
Event Category: None
Event ID:   9961
Date:       9/30/2008
Time:       4:42:11 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   Server15
Description:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at Membership.OracleMembershipProvider.GetApplicationId(String applicationName, Boolean createIfNeeded) in OracleMembershipProvider.cs:line 1626

I've looked at this from every angle that I can conceive of...  basically, no matter how I wrap it, the Execute fails.

Answer (score 1):

I notice your CommandText doesn't contain the specified parameter ":applicationName"

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error in "ExecuteReader". It's an error in the execution of the query... is `applicationName` null?